# Clojure Recursion with Data Structure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I've tried several versions of this Clojure routine but it always results in a null pointer. How can I eliminate the errors?

```
(defn loopthru [n] (
  (if-not (empty? n) (
       (println (first n))
       (loopthru (rest n))
  ))
))
(loopthru [1 2 3 4 5 6])
```

Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn loopthru [col]
  (doseq [n col] (println n)))

(defn loopthru [f col]
  (doseq [item col] (f item)))
```

Answer (score 6):

As everyone pointed out, you have double parentheses around your `if-not` macro which is not correct. (Double parentheses are rarely correct in Clojure, unlike Scheme.) But there is also another problem in your if special form. There should be a `do` special form which evaluates the s-expressions in order.

```
(defn loopthru [n]
  (if-not (empty? n)
    (do (println (first n))
     (loopthru (rest n)))))
```

A couple of other things. Use `when` / `when-not` in cases where you do not have an else block in your if statement. In fact, using `when-not` in this case eliminates the need for `do` since there is no ambiguity in the s-expressions with respect to the conditional. And I have to mention the obligatory comment that recursion in this case will chew up stack space so use `recur` instead

```
(defn loopthru [n]
  (when-not (empty? n)
    (println (first n))
    (recur (rest n))))
```

Comment: another alternative (maybe more idiomatic?) would be use (when (seq n) ...) instead (when-not (empty? n) ...)

Comment: Julian, it makes a difference if the "do" is added, doesn't it?  No one else suggested that. That gave the the desired result. Maybe you tested before posting your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The pair of parentheses around the body of the function should be omitted.  Then it will work.

Comment: I removed the pair of parens but it didn't help

Comment: You have two too many pairs. Parens are not for grouping, they are for calling functions. `(defn loopthru [n] (if-not (empty? n) (println (first n)) (loopthru (rest n))))`

Comment: @amalloy, the code as you have it does not print the numbers 1 through six